# Inserting duplicate data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to add some data to a mysql table. When I attempt to create the row I use this code:

```
$sqlJetId = "INSERT INTO orders (jetId, amazonId, name, phoneNumber, addr1, addr2, city, state, zipcode, sku, quantity, carrier, method, trackingNumber, rejected, reasonRejected, cancel, returned, complete, error) VALUES ('$jetId', '', '$name', '$phoneNumber', '$addr1', '$addr2', '$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$sku', '$quantity', '$carry', '$level', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')";
$resultJetId = $sqlConnection->query($sqlJetId);
if ($sqlConnection->query($sqlJetId) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sqlJetId . "<br>" . $sqlConnection->error;
}
```

There is no errors that occur, but the values do not insert into the sql table.

This code is inside of a foreach loop. Here is the full foreach loop:

```
foreach($url as $jetId)
{
   $skus = array();
   $ItemId = array();

   $jetAPI->getOrderDetail();
   if($detail = json_decode($detailResponse))      
   {
     if($orderDetail = $detail->order_detail);
     { 
         $carry = $orderDetail->request_shipping_carrier;
         $level = $orderDetail->request_service_level;
     }
     if($shipto = $detail->shipping_to)
     {
         if($shipto->recipient)
         {
             $name = $shipto->recipient->name;
             $phoneNumber = $shipto->recipient->phone_number;                        
         }
         if($shipto->address)
         {
             $addr1 = $shipto->address->address1;
             $addr2 = $shipto->address->address2;
             $city = $shipto->address->city;
             $state = $shipto->address->state;
             $zipcode = $shipto->address->zip_code;
         }        
     }
     if($itemsOrdered = $detail->order_items)
     {
         foreach($itemsOrdered as $itemOrdered)
         {
             $orderItemId = $itemOrdered->order_item_id;
             $sku = $itemOrdered->merchant_sku;
             $quantity = $itemOrdered->request_order_quantity;
             $cancel = $itemOrdered->request_order_cancel_qty;
             $skus[] = $sku;
             $quantityOrdered[] = $quantity;
         }
         $sku = implode(',' , $skus);
         $quantity = implode(',' , $quantityOrdered);
     }
     $jetId = substr($jetId, 30);
 }
 $sqlJetId = "INSERT INTO orders (jetId, amazonId, name, phoneNumber, addr1, addr2, city, state, zipcode, sku, quantity, carrier, method, trackingNumber, rejected, reasonRejected, cancel, returned, complete, error) VALUES ('$jetId', '', '$name', '$phoneNumber', '$addr1', '$addr2', '$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$sku', '$quantity', '$carry', '$level', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')";
 $resultJetId = $sqlConnection->query($sqlJetId);
 if ($sqlConnection->query($sqlJetId) === TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sqlJetId . "<br>" . $sqlConnection->error;
 }
}
```

Please let me know if i am doing something wrong. I would greatly appreciate it. I need the data to be inserted into the sql table.

Here is some test data that i am using:

```
stdClass Object
(
[buyer] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => 'Bart Simpson'
        [phone_number] => '212-212-4766'
    )

[customer_reference_order_id] => 002241836938
[fulfillment_node] => 29b7756343db41929281828b8fd46112
[has_shipments] => 
[hash_email] => 687931655832@customer.jet.com
[jet_request_directed_cancel] => 
[merchant_order_id] => 1c3397fae30747c381f8ed43a0355396
[order_detail] => stdClass Object
    (
        [request_shipping_carrier] => UPS
        [request_service_level] => Expedited
        [request_ship_by] => 2016-02-09T22:55:54.1834573Z
        [request_delivery_by] => 2016-02-10T22:55:54.1834573Z
    )

[order_items] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [order_item_id] => bc4f8a9a396f4ba2bace409b136c8282
                [merchant_sku] => Rubies_32295
                [request_order_quantity] => 2
                [request_order_cancel_qty] => 0
                [item_tax_code] => 
                [item_price] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [item_tax] => 
                        [item_shipping_cost] => 0.66
                        [item_shipping_tax] => 
                        [base_price] => 10.99
                    )

                [product_title] => Star Wars: The Force Awakens Child\'s Stormtrooper Half Helmet
                [url] => "http://www.jet.com/api/merchant_skus/Rubies_32295"
            )

    )

[order_placed_date] => 2016-02-08T22:54:54.1834573Z
[order_totals] => stdClass Object
    (
        [item_price] => stdClass Object
            (
                [item_tax] => 
                [item_shipping_cost] => 1.32
                [item_shipping_tax] => 
                [base_price] => 21.98
            )

    )

[order_transmission_date] => 2016-02-08T22:55:54.1834573Z
[reference_order_id] => 878597791383
[shipping_to] => stdClass Object
    (
        [recipient] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Maggie Simpson
                [phone_number] => 212-212-3939
            )

        [address] => stdClass Object
            (
                [address1] => 26 Birch street
                [address2] => 
                [city] => Old Cairo
                [state] => MS
                [zip_code] => 38829
            )

    )

[status] => ready
)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First thing I see if variables in the first snippet single quoted. Remove the single quotes or double quote them. e.g. "INSERT INTO orders (jetId, amazonId, name, phoneNumber, addr1, addr2, city, state, zipcode, sku, quantity, carrier, method, trackingNumber, rejected, reasonRejected, cancel, returned, complete, error) VALUES ('$jetId', '', '$name', '$phoneNumber', '$addr1', '$addr2', '$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$sku', '$quantity', '$carry', '$level', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')"; $jetId, '', $name, etc...

Comment: That was already done.

Comment: Can you try running the sql directly and then use static values and run in in php? That may point to an issue in your values. Try to var_dump the values individually in your insert after to debug.

Comment: I got everything to insert. I just added new tables. Thanks.